# Unable to access store with pinia

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pinia

I have a login page hooked up to firebase and I'm trying to use pinia to update the state to login the user after registering. I'm having a problem that whenever it tries to access the state I get "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.userStore is undefined"

Pinia Store:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export default defineStore('user', {
    state: () => ({
        userLoggedIn: false,
    }),
})
```

RegisterForm:

```
<script>
import { auth, usersCollection } from "@/includes/firebase";
import { mapWritableState } from 'pinia';
import useUserStore from "@/stores/user";

export default {
  name: "registerForm",
  
  computed: {
    ...mapWritableState(useUserStore, ['userLoggedIn'])
    
  },
  mounted() {
      console.log(this.userStore.userLoggedIn);
    },
```

console logged the login state for testing, but shows undefined. Not sure what the issue is. I have another store setup the same way and it works just fine.

same for my methods to actually trigger the state from false to true. Having the console log "this.userLoggedIn" works, but does not work in the methods.

```
methods: {
    async register(values) {
      this.reg_show_alert = true;
      this.reg_in_submission = true;
      this.reg_alert_variant = "bg-blue-500";
      this.reg_alert_msg = "Please wait! You account is bring created.";

      let userCred = null;
      try {
        userCred = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          values.email,
          values.password
        );
      } catch (error) {
        this.reg_in_submission = false;
        this.reg_alert_variant = "bg-red-500";
        this.reg_alert_msg =
          "An unexpected error occured. Please try again later.";
        return;
      }

      try {
        await usersCollection.add({
          name: values.name,
          email: values.email,
          age: values.age,
          country: values.country,
        });
        
      } catch (error) {
        this.reg_in_submission = false;
        this.reg_alert_variant = "bg-red-500";
        this.reg_alert_msg =
          "An unexpected error occured. Please try again later.";
        return;
      }

      this.userStore.userLoggedIn = true;         

      this.reg_alert_variant = "bg-green-500";
      this.reg_alert_msg = "You account has been created";
      console.log(userCred);
      
      
    },
  },
```

Comment: In Vue2+VueX, I do a similar thing (mapping object via computed), but when I use it there's no reference to any "store". So, it would be `console.log(this.userLoggedIn)`. Try that?

Comment: I think you just want `this.userLoggedIn`. See [the docs](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/state.html#usage-with-the-options-api)

Answer (score 0):

> **In your store file**

```
export const useUserStore = defineStore("user", {
  state: () => ({ userLoggedIn: false })
});
```

> **In your, register form**

```
import { mapWritableState } from "pinia";
import { useUserStore } from "@/store";

computed: {
    ...mapWritableState(useUserStore, [
      "userLoggedIn",
    ]),
},
mounted() {
  console.log(this.userLoggedIn);
  //You can directly modify your state value.
  this.userLoggedIn = true;
  console.log(this.userLoggedIn);
},
```